# How to hook custom taxonomies to custom post types and make the permalinks work?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

So,

I have my custom post type with the slug **/news**. And I want my category view to be **/news/category/CATEGORYID**.

For that I create my custom taxonomy:

```
add_action('init', 'create_allfilmnews_categories', 0);
function create_allfilmnews_categories() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search categories' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All category' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent category:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit category' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add new category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New category name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'News categories' ),
    );  

    register_taxonomy('news_category', 'news', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'category' ),
    ));
}
```

I was hoping, that since it is hooked to **news** custom post-type.. and its slug is "category", so I was hoping that naturally it would work out like I wanted (/news/category/CATEGORYID). And use my custom category-template just by creating a file to the template directory: **category-news_category.php**.

However, of course it is not working.

Is it even possible to have a custom taxonomy aka. categories inside custom post-type, that work perfectly with permalinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things - I think the category URL would be: yourdomain.com/news_category/NEWS-CATEGORY-SLUG-HERE

So for example if you created a category "top headlines" in your "news_category" taxonomy... it would look like this (assuming the slug for "top headlines" is "top-headlines"):

/news_category/top-headlines/

The second thing...
I think your template name should be "taxonomy-news_category.php"

(edited to add - I don't think you can have the slug be "category" as that is being used by WordPress already.. so that may be causing a conflict in itself...I could be wrong on that though...)

Comment: Your right on the money! I actually got this EXACTLY the same method working last night. My overall solution was, that the custom taxonomy slug was simply: "news/category" and indeed the template-name for custom taxonomy would be taxonomy-news_category.php Works 100% like I wanted.